# como agregar a un objeto ya creado una propiedad al principio del mismo (y no al final) ? JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

```html
let objeto = {
  propiedadA: 'algun texto',
  propiedadB: 'algun texto'
}

objeto.id = 1
```

Despues de agregar el id queda así:

```
let objeto = {
  propiedadA: 'algun texto',
  propiedadB: 'algun texto',
  id: 1
}
```

Como puedo agregar la propiedad `id` pero al principio, es decir antes de la `propiedadA`?

Comment: Hasta ES2015, [los objetos en Javascript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) no garantizan el orden de las propiedades, lo que hoy funciona de una forma, puede no funcionar igual en otro momento, dependiendo del entorno. Saludos

Comment: hola Sequie, te he dejado una respuesta explicando, como resolver el problema del orden de la propiedades; el cual la resuelve de manera enumerable. cualquier consulta me escriben en la respuesta para darte apoyo, si alguna de las respuesta resuelven tu duda; recuerda marcarla como respuesta.

Comment: si alguna de las respuestas en tus preguntas solucionan tus dudas, recuerda marcaslas como solucionadas.

Answer (score 3):

Para realizar la addicion de propiedades al inicio de un objeto, implementaremos el estadar ES6 de 2015+ soportada por la mayoria de navegadores actuales.

Para lograr esto utilizaremos el metodo nativo de javascript: `Object.assign()`

Podras encontrar la documentacion [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

> Las propiedades del objeto de destino se sobrescriben con las
> propiedades de los orígenes si tienen la misma clave. Las propiedades
> de las fuentes posteriores sobrescriben las anteriores.
>
> El método `Object.assign()` solo copia propiedades enumerables y propias
> de un objeto de origen a un objeto de destino. Utiliza `[[Get]]` en el
> origen y `[[Set]]` en el destino, por lo que invocará `getters` y `setters`.
> Por lo tanto, asigna propiedades, en lugar de copiar o definir nuevas
> propiedades. Esto puede hacer que no sea adecuado para fusionar nuevas
> propiedades en un prototipo si las fuentes de fusión contienen
> captadores.

***Ejemplo:***

```js
let objeto = {
  propiedadA: 'algun texto',
  propiedadB: 'algun texto'
};
objeto = Object.assign({id: 1}, objeto);

console.log(objeto);
```

Como podras observar al momento de ejecutar el codigo el script agregara al inicio del objeto la propiedad `id` con el valor que indicaste.

**Porque lo agrega al inicio?**

`Object.assign()` tiene una característica y es que agregara las propiedades que sean y se puedan enumerar o sean enumerable, si agregamos la propiedad que comience con una Z, este la agregara al final.

Es importante que sepas que esto no funcionaba de esta forma antes de ES6 del 2015.

Comment: Te doy tu +1 porque me sorprendiste, jamás pensé que la solución a un problema tan especifico y simple, se podía explicar en tantas líneas y de una manera tan enredad.

Comment: @Yussef por ese motivo hay programadores que solo saben copiar y pegar código... y no saben de donde salen las cosas... el que viene aquí buscando una respuesta a lo mejor solo le interesa el código, pero nuestras respuestas no son solo para el OP, son para toda la comunidad. de esa misma forma si un empleador busca tu perfil en esta red... verá si solo copias código o si sabes explicar lo. que haces y conoces por que y de donde vienen  las cosas...

Comment: @Yussef la idea del sitio no es solo encontrar la solucion, si no que tambien la puedas aplicar a otros problemas similares. Por eso, la explicacion nunca esta de mas, tal vez el problema de la proxima persona no sea exactamente igual, pero una solucion explicada le lleve a encontrar la solucion a su problema...

Comment: @gbianchi Llevo 19 días en el sitio, antes de mi primera respuesta di el tour y busqué en la ayuda para ver cómo debía responde. Si tu pudieras ayudarme y decir donde dice eso que me comentas te estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: @Yussef no esta explicito en la ayuda. Es la filosofia del sitio, y si usuarios con mas años que tu te lo estan diciendo, es por algo. Dentro de todos los apartados de ayuda, se pide que las respuestas sean claras, completas, expliquen el problema y den una solucion que pueda ser aportada a problemas similares. Las respuestas que son solo codigo se consideran de baja calidad. Que pasa si me das tu codigo, y mi codigo no era exacto como lo muestro (por problemas de copyrigth por ejemplo) como lo traduzco? si me explicas el contexto, puedo hacerlo. Si son solo lineas, es muy difcil.

Comment: @Yussef si quieres, lo hablamos en el [chat]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar spread operator, quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
let objeto = {
  propiedadA: 'algun texto',
  propiedadB: 'algun texto'
}

objeto = {id: 1, ...objeto}

console.log(objeto)
```

Dejo link de documentación a spread operator.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Básicamente lo que hace esta línea: `objeto = {id: 1, ...objeto}` es reasignar a la variable objeto un nuevo objeto donde primero se agrega la propiedad id y luego con el spread operator se esparce o dispersa cada una de las propiedades del objeto original y se agregan en el nuevo objeto, es decir, es como hacer lo siguiente:

```
objeto = {id: 1, propiedadA: objeto.propiedadA, propiedadB: objeto.propiedadB}
```

Comment: recuerda agregar que esto solo funciona en objetos iterables.